# Second sequential function stomps the first function

Tags: php, function, header

I guess I have to break down and ask for help. (Should have done it 3 days ago!)

Here's what happens...

- PHP reads session & post variables, builds a .csv file from a mysql query.
- it attempts to open a 'Save As' dialog box and when that's done, jump to another page.
- I'm using nested functions but when run, the dialog box seems to get run over and never appears.
- separately the functions work fine.
- when run, the 'save as' dialog box doesn't wait for user input
- Can anyone see what I've done wrong or can you redirect my thinking?
- $filename points to the created CSV file on the server
- $suggname is a default filename users should see in the dialog box.

The code:

```
holdit($filename,$suggname);

function holdit($filename,$suggname) {
  $fp=@fopen($filename, 'rb');
  if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE")) {
    header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$suggname.'"' );
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
  } else {
    header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$suggname.'"' );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
  }
  fpassthru($fp);
  fclose($fp);
  jump();
}

function jump() {
    header('Location: return_from_csv.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding lots of headers to your HTTP response. One of those is `Location` which instructs the browser to redirect. Obviously it is interpreting that as a higher priority than your other headers.

Decide if you want to redirect or serve a file in your response and do one or the other.

I suspect you have misunderstood the `Location` header. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

By the looks of things you are trying to serve the CSV file and then redirect to another page. Sorry, you cannot do this. An HTTP response does one thing and one thing only. You might consider opening your link to the CSV file in another window using the `target` attribute of `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks Joe ... I guess I thought the first dialog function would have to complete before the redirect in the second function was even called. I'll pursue your suggestion and thanks for answering. ... Jim